# How to Split datatable into multiple datatable using particular id without using linq in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset, datarow

I want to split single DataTable into multiple `DataTable`s.

Table1 contains clientid, clientname

> (1,client1)(1,client2)(1,client3)(2,client4)(2,client5)

I want to split this table into

> table2 = (1,client1)(1,client2)(1,client3)

and

> table3 will have (2,client4)(2,client5).

The same clientid `DataRow`s will moved to a separate `DataTable`. How can I do that?

I tried, but it's not working.  I want to do this without linq in c#.  How to Split datatable into multiple datatable using particular id without using linq in c#?

```
foreach (DataRow row in dsBindSubCategory.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    DataRow newRow = newDt.NewRow();
    newRow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
    newDt.Rows.Add(newRow);
    i++;

    if (Convert.ToInt32(dsBindSubCategory.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ClientId"]) != Convert.ToInt32(dsBindSubCategory.Tables[0].Rows[i - 1]["ClientId"]))
    {
        newDs.Tables.Add(newDt);
        j++;
        newDt = dsBindSubCategory.Tables[0].Clone();
        newDt.TableName = "Table_" + j;
        newDt.Clear();
        i = 0;
    }
}

return newDs;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to avoid linq?

Comment: By using this, List<DataTable> subTables = (dsBindSubCategory.Tables[0]).AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("ClientId")).Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable()).ToList(); I achieved my result. I can not bind those results into the gridview.

Comment: Hold on, you want to bind multiple `DataTable`s to a single `GridView`?

Comment: This actually is starting to sound like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What's your end game?  You might be going in the wrong direction.

Comment: spliting dataset into multiple datatable and create dynamic gridview and bind them

Comment: A single `GridView` or a multiple `GridView`s?  If this is for a single `GridView`, then why don't you just perform an ordering to keep like items together, unless I'm not understanding what you're trying to do....

Answer (score 0):

The following code will create two data tables from one data table.  Note that I'm creating the original table in code as well, since I don't have access to your data source.

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("clientid");
    DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("clientname");

    col1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    col2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");

    table.Columns.Add(col1);
    table.Columns.Add(col2);

    DataRow r = table.NewRow();
    r[col1] = 1;
    r[col2] = "client 1";
    table.Rows.Add(r);
    r = table.NewRow();
    r[col1] = 1;
    r[col2] = "client 2";
    table.Rows.Add(r);
    r = table.NewRow();
    r[col1] = 2;
    r[col2] = "client 3";
    table.Rows.Add(r);

    // Create two new data tables
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("t1");
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("t2");
    // Make the columns of the new tables match the existing table columns
    foreach(DataColumn dc in table.Columns)
    {
        dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType));
        dt2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType));
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["clientid"]);
        if (id == 1)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
            dr.SetField("clientid", row["clientid"]);
            dr.SetField("clientname", row["clientname"]);
            dt1.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        else
        {
            DataRow dr = dt2.NewRow();
            dr.SetField("clientid", row["clientid"]);
            dr.SetField("clientname", row["clientname"]);
            dt2.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
}
```

So, obviously this is creating just two tables.  Since your comment says you want multiple new data tables for each unique id, you'd want to use the following code:

```
    DataTable newTable= new DataTable();
    // Make the columns of the new tables match the existing table columns
    foreach(DataColumn dc in table.Columns)
    {
        newTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType));
        newTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType));
    }
```

each time you iterate through the rows in the source table and find a new clientid.  You'd probably want some sort of dictionary of ids and new result tables to keep track of things.  If you need more details I can try to write up a more full example, but the concept is the same.

Comment: The main data table clientId are dynamic.It can be 2 or more. Based on those I want to create multiple datatable.so how do i do that.

Comment: But I have seventeen columns in my main table.Each time when i creating split table i want to mention those for "newTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType));" .Is there any other solution. Now what I am trying is  compare current rows and the next rows in datarow if clientid different in the next row, then split into seperate datatable.

Answer (score 0):

You may create DataViews and copy them to dataTables:

```
DataView DataView1 = new DataView(table,"ClientId=1","ClientId ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
DataTable dt1 = DataView1.Table.Clone();
```

Comment: The main data table clientId are dynamic.It can be 2 or more. Based on those I want to create multiple datatable.so how do i do that.

Comment: You may change the filter expression dynamically, as for a WHERE SQL clause i.e.:    new DataView (table,Expression, ..., ...)